# How does showdow work in datetime2?

Tags: languages, datetime2

Since `datetime` is no longer getting bug fixes, I've been looking at the possibility of switching to `datetime2`. However, aside from the fact that I'd need to write my own language module, I can't even get to grips with the existing module for English.

Suppose that I want mostly to produce textual dates with the default settings for my locale and I'm using British English at the document level. At some point in the document, though, I'd like to switch the style in which dates are displayed so that the day of the week is also printed.

I'm trying:

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[calc]{datetime2}
\DTMsetup{useregional}

\begin{document}
\DTMlangsetup[british]{showdow}\today
\end{document}
```

I've also tried passing `useregional` and `showdow` as options to `datetime2` when loading the package but then I get a compilation error. I've tried `en-GB`, too, because `datetime2` doesn't always recognise the `british` alias. But I didn't get far with that either. And I've tried using the `\DTMlangsetup` in the preamble with no better luck.

The error I'm getting is

```
Package datetime2 Warning: Region `british' has ignored 
(datetime2)                the following settings:
(datetime2)                showdow
 on input line 22.
```

Since I've got a fix for Welsh support in `datetime`, this is no longer of the immediate interest it was since I'd have to write a language module to switch to `datetime2` (rather than just correcting a `.def` file). But I'd still like to know how `datetime2` thinks even though I've no intention of switching unless I really have to. (I'm hoping something I understand better may turn up before then!)

I admit that I find the package extremely confusing: I have no idea at all how the different commands and different files are supposed to play nicely together. (This is not a criticism of the author: `datetime2` is just much more ambitious than `datetime` and I simply don't understand the key concepts underlying its organisational structure.) But I thought from the documentation that `showdow` ought to work with British English and I don't understand why it doesn't.

Comment: Here's the unsatisfying answer: you can keep everything the same, except for your call to `datetime2`, which "should" instead read `\usepackage[useregional,showdow,calc]{datetime2}`.

Comment: @jon So it is not possible to toggle `showdow` within a document? Either it is on or it is off, and that's it? If so, `datetime2` is much less flexible on this than `datetime`, and the documentation should make this limitation much clearer, along with explicit guidance on how to enable it.

Comment: Well, I wonder too.  That's why I wrote '"should"' and why I kept it in a comment. I figured the package author would be along soon enough to give a canonical answer that didn't require scare quotes.

Answer (score 4):

I've added some more information to the manual for `datetime2` v1.2, which I've just uploaded, regarding the `showdow` setting, but I'll try to clarify.

The `showdow` setting really ought to be a language-dependent (or contrib package) setting as it's not used by the main `datetime2` code and isn't used by a lot of styles, so I did intend to implement it in the same way as the language settings, such as `abbr`, but the `showdow` option requires the `datetime2-calc` package, which calculates the day of week number. Without this extra package, the day of week number can't be calculated, which limits the use of `showdow` to those commands where the user has explicitly entered the day of week number, for example `\DTMdisplaydate{2015}{11}{10}{1}`.

I thought it might not be intuitively obvious to most users that they would have to either explicitly load `datetime2-calc` or use `\usepackage[calc]{datetime2}` if they wanted to use the `showdow` setting, so I decided to make `showdow` a package option, which automatically loads `datetime2-calc`. I'm sorry if this has confused people.

Since `showdow` is a package-wide option rather than a language option it can be set using `\DTMsetup`, but an attempt to switch it on in the `document` environment without the `datetime2-calc` package loaded will cause an error. Since this is controlled by the base `datetime2` package, this means that the mechanism doesn't have to rely on each language module performing this check.

If you want to define a style that adds a check for the `showdow` setting, you can use:

```
 \ifDTMshowdow
   \ifnum##4>-1 % space needed after -1
     % code that inserts the day of week name
     % where the day of week index is given by ##4
   \fi
 \fi
```

at the appropriate place where you want to add the weekday name.

(This should be in the redefinition of `\DTMdisplaydate` and `\DTMDisplaydate`. Where this occurs inside `\DTMnewdatestyle` or `\DTMnewstyle` this requires `##4` instead of `#4` to reference the day of week index argument.)

The check for `-1` is needed in addition to the check for `showdow` to allow the user to explicitly ignore the day of week name regardless of the `showdow` setting. This is primarily for cases where the date must be fully expandable (for example, in PDF bookmarks) which can't be done with the non-expandable commands, such as `\DTMdate`, that have to calculate the day of week index.

For example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[showdow,en-GB]{datetime2}

\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{\DTMdisplaydate{2015}{11}{10}{1}}

\section{\DTMdisplaydate{\year}{\month}{\day}{-1}}

\end{document}
```

(You can get around this by first saving the date, including the day of week number, and then using it in the expandable context, but a user might not want to do this.)