# How do I extract a month name in datetime2?

Tags: datetime2

In `datetime`, there was a macro which provided the long name of the month, so if I have saved a date as, say, `gitdate`, I can extract the month name by:

```
\monthname{\getdatemonth{gitdate}}
```

Is there something similar in `datetime2`? I couldn't find anything in the manual, so I tried

```
\DTMfetchmonthname{gitdate}
```

but that was a bit optimistic.

Of course, I appreciate that `datetime2` brings a whole lot more rigour to the story, and that international month names can be a bit stress-inducing, but I live in hope.

---

The two answers so far (@cfr and @egreg, in alphabetical order) are excellent(+1), but don't entirely solve my problem. `babel` (or my preference, `polyglossia`) seems like an awful lot of baggage to carry around for a simple monolingual document. It would be "nicer" if there were, in the absence of these packages, a "sensible default".

---

I can confirm that @cfr's solution using `babel` works correctly.

Unfortunately, substituting `polyglossia` for `babel` appears to fail.

Comment: A complete example would be best here. The language modules define additional macros so what works for one language - or one variant of one language - may not work for another. Personally, I'm still using `datetime` with a fixed language file. I can't figure out how to transition to `datetime2` ;).

Comment: @cfr I'm sorry, I don't think I can improve on that too much. I'll update the question to clarify a bit, but I really haven't a clue.

Comment: The thing is, a complete example would make it possible to say for sure whether you can do this or not. I've answered with a couple of examples but you'll need to investigate the module(s) you are using to see if something analogous would work for you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do this for a particular language or variant if the relevant module supports it, using the commands provided by that module. Without a complete example, I can't say whether this is possible for your situation or not because I don't have a clue what your preamble is.

For British English, for example, I can do this:

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{datetime2}
\DTMsetup{useregional}

\begin{document}
\DTMsavenow{thisone}
\DTMenglishmonthname{\DTMfetchmonth{thisone}}
\end{document}
```

[image: fancy way to typeset current month]

But `\DTMenglishmonthname` is obviously specific to the various variants of English supported by `datetime2-english`. Another language module may not provide a similar facility - it just depends on the particular module.

Something analogous works for Welsh, although the particular command obviously differs:

```
\documentclass[welsh]{article}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{datetime2}
\DTMsetup{useregional}

\begin{document}
\DTMsavenow{thisone}
\DTMwelshmonthname{\DTMfetchmonth{thisone}}
\end{document}
```

[image: Awst]

There doesn't seem to be a language-agnostic user-level macro for retrieving the name of the month, though. But perhaps there is and I'm just not seeing it - as I say, I've failed miserably in my attempt to transition to `datetime2` and am, therefore, still using `datetime`.

Comment: I see nowhere that an option such as `british` or `en-UK` sets in any way a string representing the current language so that one can dynamically define `\DTMmonthname` in such a way it uses `\DTM<language>monthname`. On the other hand, if you use the interface to `babel`, doing `\def\DTMmonthname{\csname DTM\languagename monthname\endcsname}` might work.

Comment: @egreg Even if you can, there's no guarantee that the language module will provide `\DTM<language>monthname` as far as I can tell, and the package doesn't provide any fallback, I don't think, so the command might just be undefined.

Answer (score 7):

I've updated this answer following the release of `datetime2` v1.3.

1. Each language module provides a command in the form `\DTM`*lang*`monthname` where *lang* is the root language name (e.g. `\DTMfrenchmonthname` provided by `datetime2-french` or `\DTMenglishmonthname` provided by `datetime2-english`). This command has a required argument and may be used in expandable contexts. It's analogous to `datetime`'s `\monthname`*language* commands (e.g. `\monthnamefrench` provided by `dt-french.def` or `\monthnameenglish` provided by `datetime-defaults.sty`). The `datetime` version can't be used in expandable contexts and has an optional argument.

   Some of the language modules may additionally provide alternative commands. For example, the `datetime2-usorbian` module provides `\DTMusorbiannewmonthname` and `\DTMusorbianoldmonthname`, and the `datetime2-serbian` module provides `\DTMserbiancyrmonthname` and `\DTMserbianlatinmonthname`. In these cases, `\DTM`*lang*`monthname` is set to whatever command is the default. This can be changed through the language module options (such as the `style` key for the `usorbian` module or the `alphabet` key for the `serbian` module).

Example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[french,british]{babel}
\usepackage{datetime2}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}

\pagestyle{headings}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\clearpage

\section{\DTMenglishmonthname{1} (English)}

\section{\DTMfrenchmonthname{1} (French)}

\end{document}
```

This produces

[image: image of table of contents]

on the first page, and

[image: image of second page]

on the second page. The PDF bookmarks appear correctly:

[image: image of bookmarks]

For comparison, the analogous `datetime` code is:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[french,british]{babel}
\usepackage{datetime}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}

\pagestyle{headings}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\clearpage

\section{\monthnameenglish[1] (English)}

\section{\monthnamefrench[1] (French)}

\end{document}
```

The first page looks the same as the `datetime2` example, but the second page is incorrect as the month name hasn't been converted to upper case in the header:

[image: image of second page]

The PDF bookmarks are also incorrect:

[image: image of PDF bookmarks]

2. Since `datetime2-calc` automatically loads the `pgfcalendar` package, you can use the month name commands provided by that package, so `\pgfcalendarmonthname` is the nearest equivalent to `datetime`'s `\monthname` command, but it requires the `translator` package.

Modifying the above example:

```
\documentclass[french,british]{article}

\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{translator}
\usepackage[calc]{datetime2}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}

\pagestyle{headings}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\clearpage

\selectlanguage{british}
\section{\pgfcalendarmonthname{1} (English)}

\selectlanguage{french}
\section{\pgfcalendarmonthname{1} (French)}

\end{document}
```

This produces

[image: image of table of contents]

on the first page and

[image: image of second page]

on the second page, but the PDF bookmarks are incorrect:

[image: image of PDF bookmarks]

This produces a warning from `hyperref` because it can't process `\translate`.

The equivalent `datetime` version of this example is

```
\documentclass[french,british]{article}

\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{datetime}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}

\pagestyle{headings}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\clearpage

\selectlanguage{british}
\section{\monthname[1] (English)}

\selectlanguage{french}
\section{\monthname[1] (French)}

\end{document}
```

This produces

[image: image of table of contents]

on the first page and

[image: image of second page]

on the second page. Again the page header is incorrect as `\monthname` can't be converted to upper case. The PDF bookmarks are also incorrect:

[image: image of PDF bookmarks]

3. As from version 1.3, the `datetime2-calc` package now provides `\DTMmonthname`, which is the closest match to `datetime`'s `\monthname` command. This new command is robust and works as follows: it tries to determine if `\DTM`*lang*`monthname` exists, first with *lang* set to `\languagename` and, if that fails, with *lang* set to `\TrackedLanguageFromDialect{\languagename}`. If the command `\DTM`*lang*`monthname` command exists, it's used. If not, the `\pgfcalendarmonthname` command is used instead with a warning. (If this occurs, it most likely means the appropriate `datetime2` language module hasn't been installed or loaded.)

Adapting the previous example from `datetime` to `datetime2`:

```
\documentclass[french,british]{article}

\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[calc]{datetime2}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}

\pagestyle{headings}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\clearpage

\selectlanguage{british}
\section{\DTMmonthname{1} (English)}

\selectlanguage{french}
\section{\DTMmonthname{1} (French)}

\end{document}
```

This pretty much produces the same result as the previous `datetime` example. The only difference is in the PDF bookmarks, which are again incorrect, but just incorrect in a slightly different way:

[image: image of PDF bookmarks]

So the closest match to `\monthname[`*n*`]` is `\DTMmonthname{`*n*`}`, which has all the same drawbacks as the original `datetime` command.

---

### Original Answer

I deliberately wanted to avoid a general month name macro in `datetime2` because it caused problems with `datetime` when users used a style with the syntax of one language (overriding `babel`'s date switching mechanism) but the month name from the language currently in use (because the style used `\monthname`). The base `datetime2` package only deals with numeric styles, and my intention was to ensure that all language/region settings were dealt with by the language modules. (The `showdow` option is an exception to this, see [How does showdow work in datetime2?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/260989/how-does-showdow-work-in-datetime2)) There were three main points I particularly wanted to address:

1. Prevent accidental mixing of syntax and translated fixed names.
2. Allow the language modules flexibility when implementing month names, as some languages have alternative month names ([as in a recent question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/275027/change-month-names-in-today-command)) or alternative styles. Perhaps a language module might provide "new style" and "old style" date formats. This kind of variation makes a simple `\monthname` mapping much more complicated and less intuitive.
3. Ensure date styles are fully expandable (as much as possible) to allow for use in PDF bookmarks. What should happen if a language module hasn't been loaded and you tried to use `\csname DTM\languagename monthname`? Silently ignore it (and confuse users) or issue a warning or error (in which case this could cause more obscure errors in certain contexts).

However, since the language modules provide the settings `showdayofmonth` and `showyear`, you can fetch just the month name by setting both to `false`. For example:

```
\documentclass[french]{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[warn=false,useregional]{datetime2}

\DTMlangsetup{showdayofmonth=false,showyear=false}

\begin{document}

\edef\thismonth{\today}
\show\thismonth

\end{document}
```

This also works with `polyglossia`:

```
\documentclass[french]{article}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage[warn=false,useregional]{datetime2}

\DTMlangsetup{showdayofmonth=false,showyear=false}

\begin{document}

\edef\thismonth{\today}
\show\thismonth

\end{document}
```

**Edit:**

There's another possible solution:

```
\documentclass[french]{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{translator}
\usepackage[calc]{datetime2}

\begin{document}

\pgfcalendarmonthname{\month}

\end{document}
```

This is because `datetime2-calc` loads `pgfcalendar`, but I don't know if it has support for `polyglossia`.

Comment: In this case, I really don't think `datetime` should be declared obsolete. 'Obsolete' is used for packages whose functionality is provided by newer packages and where those newer packages are clearly preferable. `datetime` is the only package I'm aware of which provides the functionality it does. I appreciate the fact that it became a nightmare to maintain. But it is perfectly possible to declare a package unmaintained without claiming it is obsolete. In that case, other people could provide updates or fixes. I'm using a corrected language file but I'm blocked from sharing those corrections.

Comment: I did, by the way, make a genuine effort to switch to `datetime2`. I failed utterly because I need Welsh and I could not get that working. Obviously this is just due to my limitations but, on the grounds that I'm probably not the only one to suffer from such limitations, it would be nice if there was at least a `datetime` option available for Welsh. Right now the translations in both `datetime` and `datetime2` are, as you know, erroneous. (They are possibly a mix of Welsh and Breton - they are certainly a mix of Welsh and something foreign.)

Comment: But this answer makes me suspect that `datetime2` wouldn't work for me as a replacement anyway, even if I could figure it out. That's perfectly reasonable, but it convinces me that `datetime` is *not* obsolete, regardless of the stamp embossed on its CTAN page.

Comment: @cfr If someone wants to take over maintenance of `datetime` they can contact me and I'll be happy for them to resurrect it. I just have far too many free projects burdening me to spend time supporting one that has so many issues which I can't address without breaking backward compatibility.

Comment: You can disown it without declaring it obsolete. Obsolete makes it a candidate for removal from distributions because it is assumed the functionality is provided by another package. Just ceasing to maintain it doesn't do that. I don't really see the objection to this. But it is not my package, after all.

Answer (score 6):

In my opinion, the `datetime2` package should add an interface to the `\DTM<language>monthname` macros (and for the day of week macros as well). Here is an attempt:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ngerman,english]{babel}
\usepackage[ngerman,english]{datetime2}

\addto\extrasenglish{\def\DTMlanguagename{english}}
\addto\extrasngerman{\def\DTMlanguagename{german}}
\newcommand{\DTMmonthname}{\csname DTM\DTMlanguagename monthname\endcsname}

\DTMsavedate{bach}{1685-3-21}

\begin{document}

J. S. Bach was born in \DTMmonthname{\DTMfetchmonth{bach}}.

\selectlanguage{ngerman}

J. S. Bach wurde im \DTMmonthname{\DTMfetchmonth{bach}} geboren.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This doesn't work if, for example, you have requested `british` because there is no `\DTMbritishmonthname`, but `\languagename` returns `british`.

Comment: @cfr I didn't say this is a full solution.

Comment: It seems that the lack of this interface is status-by-design :(.