# Change month names in \today command

Tags: datetime, datetime2

The `\today` command will print the Latin name of the month with the `nynorsk` language option. I would like to change this by using the more traditional (and still very commonly used in speech) system of using the ordinal number "first", "second", etc. (abbreviated from "first month", "second month", etc.).

All it requires is to substitute the month names by `i X`, where `i` is the preposition "in" and `X` the ordinal, as seen in the table below. What's the most convenient way of doing that? With the `datetime2` package?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[nynorsk]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\begin{document}
\today\\

\begin{tabular}{*5{l}}
januar & i fyrste & & juli & i sjuande\\
februar & i andre & & august & i åttande\\
mars & i tredje & & september & i niande\\
april & i fjerde & & oktober & i tiande\\
mai & i femte & & november & i ellevte\\
juni & i sjette & & desember & i tolvte\\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

For those who wonder - ordinals in Norwegian are definite, so there's no need for a definite article or determiner of any kind, as in English "in *the* first (month)", "in *the* second (month)", etc.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[nynorsk]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\renewcommand\datenynorsk{%
 \def\today{\number\day.~\ifcase\month\or
    i fyrste\or i andre\or i tredje\or i fjerde\or i femte\or i sjette\or
    i sjuande\or i åttande\or i niande\or i tiande\or i ellevte\or
    i tolvte\fi
    \space\number\year}}

\begin{document}
\today


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I'm going to delete my answer in favour of this, even though I saved 22 whole bytes by pulling the `i ` out to the front:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: A member of the latex3 team should write verbose code and not try to save 22 bytes ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Since you asked for `datetime2`, you just need to redefine the month name macros:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[nynorsk]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[useregional]{datetime2}

\renewcommand*{\DTMnorskmonthname}[1]{%
  \ifcase#1
  \or
  i fyrste%
  \or
  i andre%
  \or
  i tredje%
  \or
  i fjerde%
  \or
  i femte%
  \or
  i sjette%
  \or
  i sjuande%
  \or
  i åttande%
  \or
  i niande%
  \or
  i tiande%
  \or
  i ellevte%
  \or
  i tolvte%
  \fi
}

\renewcommand*{\DTMnorskMonthname}[1]{%
  \ifcase#1
  \or
  I fyrste%
  \or
  I andre%
  \or
  I tredje%
  \or
  I fjerde%
  \or
  I femte%
  \or
  I sjette%
  \or
  I sjuande%
  \or
  I åttande%
  \or
  I niande%
  \or
  I tiande%
  \or
  I ellevte%
  \or
  I tolvte%
  \fi
}

\begin{document}
\today

Specific date: \DTMdate{2015-10-26}.
\end{document}
```

[image: 10. i ellevte 2015. Specific date: 26. i tiande 2015.]