# How to modify months names in context

Tags: context, arabic

I would like to change months names in context, in tex `\month` define the month number, names of months can be redefined with `\ifcase` [Change month names in \today command](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/275027/change-month-names-in-today-command)

How can I do the same in context (modify names of months appearing with `\date` command), appears as `\month` unavailable in context.

**Update**

Here a MWE

```
\setuppapersize[A4]
\mainlanguage[arabic]
\setupdirections[bidi=global]
\setupalign[r2l] 

\definefontfeature
  [arabic]
  [mode=node,language=dflt,script=arab,
    init=yes,medi=yes,fina=yes,isol=yes,
    liga=yes,dlig=yes,rlig=yes,tlig=yes,
    calt=yes,trep=yes,clig=yes,
    mark=yes,mkmk=yes,kern=yes,curs=yes]


\starttypescript [serif] [arabic]
  \definefontsynonym [Arabic-Regular] [name:Amiri] [features=arabic]
  \definefontsynonym [Arabic-Bold] [name:Amiri] [features=arabic]
\stoptypescript

\starttypescript [serif] [arabic] [name]
 \usetypescript[serif][fallback]
 \definefontsynonym [Serif]     [Arabic-Regular] [features=arabic]
 \definefontsynonym [SerifBold] [Arabic-Bold]    [features=arabic]
\stoptypescript

\starttypescript [Arabic]
 \definetypeface [Arabic] [rm] [serif] [arabic] [default]
 \definetypeface [Arabic] [mm] [math]  [palatino] [default]
\stoptypescript 

\setuplayout[
  grid=min,
  backspace=20mm, width=170mm,
  topspace=10mm, height=275mm,
  header=10mm,footer=10mm,
  headerdistance=2mm
  ]

\setupbodyfont[Arabic,18pt]
\setupinterlinespace[line=30pt]

\starttext

\date

\stoptext
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want to change the main language of your document (using `\mainlanguage[…]` then you can redefine the months using `\setuplabeltext`:

```
\setuplabeltext
  %% [en]  %% for a language specific setting
  [january=J,
   february=F]
```

Furthermore, if you want to change the date format used by `\date`, you can do so with `\setuplanguage`:

```
\setuplanguage
  %% [en]  %% for a language specific setting
  [date={year, \thinspace–\thinspace, mm, \thinspace–\thinspace, dd}]
```

Comment: Thanks @Marco  in my case I need just `\setuplabeltext [arabic]   [january=جانفي,
   february=فيفري]`