# Change the case of datetime2 month return

Tags: datetime, datetime2

I'm trying to automate report generation in czech. In english, there is no problem using solution from this [thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/261641/how-do-i-extract-a-month-name-in-datetime2). Same behaviour is for `\monthname` command from `datetime` package.

The problem is, that in czech the `\DTMmonthname` returns the month name in *genitive* case which is usually different from the *nominative* case.

Is `datetime2` package capable of returning different cases (in czech there are 7 different cases, in german there are 4 cases) or it holds only one case for each month?
Or there is only one way: hardcode `\foo[<case>]{<month#>}` by myself?

Comment: Have you tried `\DTMMonthname{1}`, with a capital M?

Comment: See the solutions to this question (especially Nicola Talbot's answer): [Change month names in \today command](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/275027/4778)

Comment: @RunarTrollet Yes, both capitalised and uncapitalised commands return genitive case.

Comment: @Alenanno So the "hardcoding" then? The reason is that the sencences "[written on] January 7, 2016" and "Report for January, 2016" use different cases.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't find anything in the manual about cases (in the grammatical sense), so I guess the only solution would be hardcoding. For the various "cases", no pun intended, you could use an optional argument to switch. But you still must add all the variants in the command definition manually. Unless someone thinks of a different solution.

Comment: @Alenanno This is the `<case>` option in sugegsted `\foo` command... Thanks for your suggestions anyway.

Comment: Yes, I know that's what you suggested. I was agreeing with that.

Comment: The problem is that the relevant package `datetime2-czech` is unmaintained and probably always has been unmaintained. Therefore, the support for Czech is going to be pretty generic and minimal. The problem in finding a maintainer is likely to be that it needs somebody who can understand `datetime2` and not just somebody with knowledge of Czech. I tried to understand `datetime2` and failed. Hence, I'm using `datetime` with a corrected set of language definitions for my language. (Neither `datetime` nor `datetime2` use correct translations of basic things as the original Babel was wrong.)

Comment: @cfr Another question is whether this case case is problem only for Czech and Slovak or there are other languages that may use different spellings for different cases.

Comment: It isn't different cases, but, in Welsh, the initial letter of some month and day names varies according to context, as do the words for 'month' and 'day'. However, since the current package is essentially an usable mix of Welsh and Breton, such niceties are not really a pressing problem. But whether it is specific to Czech or not isn't directly relevant, except that you might hope somebody else had written code you could use and modify :-).

Comment: The vast majority of languages are supported by packages which are simply unmaintained. There isn't really good support for date/time localisation at present.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know any Czech, so this is pure guesswork.

The [`datetime2-serbian`](http://ctan.org/pkg/datetime2-serbian) module provides Latin month names and Cyrillic month names with an option to switch between them. The [`datetime2-usorbian`](http://ctan.org/pkg/datetime2-usorbian) module provides new style month names and old style month names with an option to switch between them. It sounds as though you're looking for a similar function, so I'll use a similar method here to that employed by those language modules. If this isn't correct, please add some examples of usage to your question.

In `datetime2-czech-utf8.ldf`, replace

```
\newcommand*{\DTMczechmonthname}[1]{%
  \ifcase#1
  \or
  ledna%
  \or
  února%
  \or
  března%
  \or
  dubna%
  \or
  května%
  \or
  června%
  \or
  července%
  \or
  srpna%
  \or
  září%
  \or
  října%
  \or
  listopadu%
  \or
  prosince%
  \fi
}
```

with

```
\newcommand*{\DTMczechgenitivemonthname}[1]{%
  \ifcase#1
  \or
  ledna%
  \or
  února%
  \or
  března%
  \or
  dubna%
  \or
  května%
  \or
  června%
  \or
  července%
  \or
  srpna%
  \or
  září%
  \or
  října%
  \or
  listopadu%
  \or
  prosince%
  \fi
}
\newcommand*{\DTMczechmonthname}{\DTMczechgenitivemonthname}% default

\newcommand*{\DTMczechnominativemonthname}[1]{%
  \ifcase#1
  \or
  nominative version of ledna%
  \or
  nominative version of února%
  \or
  nominative version of března%
  \or
  nominative version of dubna%
  \or
  nominative version of května%
  \or
  nominative version of června%
  \or
  nominative version of července%
  \or
  nominative version of srpna%
  \or
  nominative version of září%
  \or
  nominative version of října%
  \or
  nominative version of listopadu%
  \or
  nominative version of prosince%
  \fi
}
```

Add similar code for the other cases that are required. Similarly for the first letter upper case `\DTMczechMonthname`.

Do the same thing in `datetime2-czech-ascii.ldf` but replace the UTF-8 characters with LaTeX commands. (The `-utf8.ldf` file is used by XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX. The `-ascii.ldf` file is used by LaTeX.)

Then in `datetime2-czech.ldf` in the block that defines the module options (commands like `\DTMdefbool` and `\DTMdefkey`) add the following:

```
\DTMdefchoicekey{czech}{month}[\val\nr]{genitive,nominative}{%
 \ifcase\nr\relax
  \renewcommand*\DTMczechmonthname{\DTMczechgenitivemonthname}%
  \renewcommand*\DTMczechMonthname{\DTMczechgenitiveMonthname}%
 \or
  \renewcommand*\DTMczechmonthname{\DTMczechnominativemonthname}%
  \renewcommand*\DTMczechMonthname{\DTMczechnominativeMonthname}%
 \fi
}
```

Similarly add the extra cases that you require.

With these changes, in your document you should be able to switch between the different cases using `\DTMlangsetup`. For example:

```
\DTMlangsetup[czech]{month=genitive}
```