# Change month names in polyglossia

Tags: polyglossia, date

Based on [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/275032/9077), the following MWE used to work:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
    \setdefaultlanguage{nynorsk}

\renewcommand\datenynorsk{%
 \def\today{\number\day.~\ifcase\month\or
    i fyrste\or i andre\or i tredje\or i fjerde\or i femte\or i sjette\or
    i sjuande\or i åttande\or i niande\or i tiande\or i ellevte\or
    i tolvte\fi
    \space\number\year}}

\begin{document}
\today
\end{document}
```

Presumably due to a recent change in [`polyglossia`](https://ctan.org/pkg/polyglossia), the command `\datenynorsk` is no longer recognized:

> ! LaTeX Error: Command \datenynorsk
>   undefined.

What do I need to change to the original code above to be able to redefine the month names in the current version of polyglossia?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to redefine `\datenorwegian@nynorsk`; I also made a few changes: the common `i` can be set by itself, with a tie after it.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{nynorsk}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\datenorwegian@nynorsk{%
  \def\today{\number\day.~i~\ifcase\month\or
    fyrste\or andre\or tredje\or fjerde\or femte\or sjette\or
    sjuande\or åttande\or niande\or tiande\or ellevte\or
    tolvte\fi
    \space\number\year
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\today

\end{document}
```

[image: text]