# Replicate behavior from datetime package with datetime2 package

Tags: datetime, datetime2

The [`datetime` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/datetime) is now obsolete and I would like to switch to the newer [`datetime2` pacakge](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/datetime2), but I am having trouble recreating the behavior that I used the `datetime` package for. The following MWE works with the `datetime` package, but causes all sorts of problems with the `datetime2` package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{datetime}
%\usepackage{datetime2}
\computedayofweek{19}{1}{2016}
\newcommand{\mydayname}{\dayofweeknameid{\the\dayofweek}}
\newcommand{\mydaynumber}{\ordinaldate{19}}
\newcommand{\mymonthname}{\monthname[1]}
\begin{document}
\mydayname, \mydaynumber \mymonthname
\end{document}
```

Is it possible to redefine `\mydayname`, `\mydaynumber`, and `\mymonthname` (with the possible addition of code before/after the definitions), so that they produce the same results with the `datetime2` package?

Comment: Welcome to the club! Just imagine what it is like trying to set this up for *another* language.... I tried and failed. I then tried to get it to work for English and found I couldn't. So I've patched up **datetime** for the other language and kept with that.

Comment: You can't do this. See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/261641/how-do-i-extract-a-month-name-in-datetime2?rq=1. In particular see [Nicola's answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/277651/). You cannot get the name of the month in a language-agnostic way. Whether you can get it at all depends on the language module. **datetime2** itself provides only numeric stuff. As I say in comments there (and have just said again, though surely Nicola is sick of me doing so), **datetime** should not, in my opinion, be stamped 'obsolete'.

Comment: It should be marked 'unmaintained'. That is not the same. **datetime2** does not provide the functionality of **datetime**. As a result, I just don't see how it can be said to render it 'obsolete'. It is no longer maintained. That is perfectly reasonable and fine.

Comment: @cfr I do not know your full use case, but the `pgfcalendar` package is pretty powerful.

Comment: To be honest, **datetime** works fine now I've substituted a patched language file. But that's an interesting suggestion: TikZ had really not occurred to me for something like this. I wonder how linguistically-savvy it is... ;). I just live in fear it may disappear.

Comment: PGF's calendar appears not to be Babel aware, which really makes life a lot easier.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If replication is all you're after, then the following should do it:

> Tuesday, 19<sup>th</sup> January

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[calc]{datetime2}
\usepackage{fmtcount}
\DTMsavedate{mydate}{2016-01-19}% \DTMsavenow{\mydate}
\newcommand{\mydayname}{\pgfcalendarweekdayname{\DTMfetchdow{mydate}}}
\newcommand{\mydaynumber}{\ordinalnum{\DTMfetchday{mydate}}}
\newcommand{\mymonthname}{\pgfcalendarmonthname{\DTMfetchmonth{mydate}}}
\begin{document}
\mydayname, \mydaynumber{} \mymonthname
\end{document}
```

[`datetime`](http://ctan.org/pkg/datetime) used to load (require) [`fmtcount`](http://ctan.org/pkg/fmtcount), which is now manually loaded in order to use `\ordinalnum`. Additionally, in order to calculate the day-of-week values, you need to add the `calc` package option. This loads and gives you access to the `pgfcalender` module, from which one can use the expandable `\pgfcalendarweekdayname` and `\pgfcalendarmonthname` (including others, if needed).

Comment: If you use `\pgfcalendardatetojulian` and `\pgfcalendarjuliantoweekday`, then there is no need for the `datetime2` package at all in this case.

Answer (score 3):

You can replicate that format using one of the little endian date styles provided by [`datetime2-english`](http://ctan.org/pkg/datetime2-english). For example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[en-GB,showdow]{datetime2}

\DTMlangsetup[en-GB]{dowdaysep={,\space},ord=raise,showyear=false}

\begin{document}
\DTMdate{2016-01-19}

\end{document}
```

Produces:

[image: Tuesday, 19th January]

More generally, `datetime` and `datetime2` provide language-specific commands for use within date styles (to ensure the words match the date syntax regardless of the surrounding language) and language-sensitive commands for standalone use.

## Language-Specific

The language-specific commands are defined in the `dt-`*dialect*`.def` files provided with `datetime` and in the independently installed `datetime2-`*language* modules provided for `datetime2`.

### Month Names

(See also [How do I extract a month name in datetime2?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/261641/how-do-i-extract-a-month-name-in-datetime2/277651#277651))

- `datetime`

  Each file `dt-`*dialect*`.def` provides the command `\monthname`*dialect* that takes an optional argument, indicating the month number. For example, with `dt-british.def`:

  ```
  \monthnamebritish[1]
  ```

  (which, in fact, uses `\monthnameenglish` provided by `datetime-defaults.sty`).

  Some languages have alternative month names, which may have been implemented with `datetime`. For example, `dt-usorbian.def` provides `\monthnamenewusorbian` and `\monthnameoldusorbian` with `\monthnameusorbian` set as a synonym for `\monthnamenewusorbian`.
- `datetime2`

  Each language file `datetime2-`*language*`.ldf` (or `datetime2-`*language*`-`*modifier*`.ldf`) provides the command `\DTM`*language*`monthname` that takes a mandatory argument, indicating the month number. For example, with `datetime2-english-base.ldf`:

  ```
  \DTMenglishmonthname{1}
  ```

  Again, there is support for regions that have variant month names. For example, [`datetime2-usorbian`](http://ctan.org/pkg/datetime2-usorbian) provides `\DTMusorbiannewmonthname` and `\DTMusorbianoldmonthname` with `\DTMusorbianmonthname` initially defined to `\DTMusorbiannewmonthname`. This module provides the `style` option, which can take the value `new` or `old` to switch between the styles. Similarly, [`datetime2-serbian`](http://ctan.org/pkg/datetime2-serbian) provides Latin and Cyrillic month names (which `datetime`'s `dt-serbian.def` doesn't provide) and an `alphabet` option to switch between them.

### Abbreviated Month Names

Some *but not all* language date styles provide abbreviated month names. If they are supported in `datetime` then they are also supported in `datetime2`. The reason for the lack of support is simply down to me not being fluent in every known language and not knowing the correct abbreviations. The advantage of the modular approach used by `datetime2` is that each language module can be maintained by someone familiar with the language, so `datetime2` modules that have been adopted may now have support added that wasn't present with `datetime`.

- `datetime`

  Where supported, the `dt-`*dialect*`.def` file provides the command `\shortmonthname`*dialect* that takes an optional argument. For example:

  ```
  \shortmonthnamebritish[1]
  ```
- `datetime2`

  Where supported, the `datetime2-`*language*`.ldf` file provides the command `\DTM`*language*`shortmonthname` that takes a mandatory argument. For example:

  ```
  \DTMenglishshortmonthname{1}
  ```

### Day of Week Name

As with the abbreviated month name, not all language settings support the day of week name (for the same reason).

- `datetime`

  Where supported, `dt-`*dialect*`.def` provides `\dayofweeknameid`*dialect*, with a mandatory argument, which must be a number from 1 (Sunday) to 7 (Saturday). For example

  ```
  \dayofweeknameidbritish{3}
  ```

  As with the month names, there may also be an abbreviated version `\shortdayofweeknameid`*dialect*.

  The day of week index can be computed from the current date using `\computedayofweek{`*day*`}{`*month*`}{`*year*`}` with the result stored in the register `\dayofweek` (as in your MWE). Date styles that implement the day of week need to use `\computedayofweek`, which means that they have to be robust.
- `datetime2`

  Where supported, `datetime2-`*language*`.ldf` provides `\DTM`*language*`weekdayname` that takes a mandatory argument, which must be in the range 0 (Monday) to 6 (Sunday). This uses a different indexing system from `datetime` in order to be compatible with `pgfcalendar`. For example

  ```
  \DTMenglishweekdayname{1}
  ```

  As with the month names, there may also be an abbreviated version `\DTM`*language*`shortweekdayname`.

  Unlike `datetime`, the `datetime2` date styles don't compute the day of week index as it should already have been computed before being passed to the style. This means that commands like `\today` and `\DTMdisplaydate` can be used in expandable contexts. The robust command `\DTMdate` internally computes the day of week index when parsing its argument using `pgfcalendar` commands through the `datetime2-calc.sty` interface, but the index can be explicitly computed from a date using `\DTMcomputedayofweekindex`. For example:

  ```
  \DTMcomputedayofweekindex{2016-01-19}{\result}
  \DTMenglishweekdayname{\result}
  ```

### Day of Month

- `datetime`

  The day of month number is formatted by the command `\ordinaldate`*dialect* provided `dt-`*dialect*`.def`. For example:

  ```
  \ordinaldatebritish{19}
  ```

  In this case, `fmtcount`'s `\ordinalnum` is used, which is actually language-sensitive and is non-expandable. The suffix can be raised or level using the package options `raise` or `level`, but not all dialects recognise those options.
- `datetime2`

  Each `datetime2-`*language*`.ldf` file provides `\DTM`*language*`ordinal` to format the day of month number. For example:

  ```
  \DTMenglishordinal{19}
  ```

  This doesn't use `fmtcount` and is expandable. Dialects that allow modifications to the ordinal suffix format usually have an `ord` setting. These settings are specific to the particular date style and are described in the documentation for the associated language module. For example, the `en-GB` style (provided by [`datetime2-english`](http://ctan.org/pkg/datetime2-english)) has an `ord` setting that allows the values `raise`, `level`, `omit` and `sc`.

Complete example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[en-GB,calc]{datetime2}

\DTMlangsetup[en-GB]{ord=raise}

\begin{document}

\DTMcomputedayofweekindex{2016-01-19}{\result}
\DTMenglishweekdayname{\result},
\DTMenglishordinal{19}
\DTMenglishmonthname{1}

\end{document}
```

## Language-Sensitive Commands

There are language-sensitive commands for standalone use of particular components of the date. With `datetime2`, you'll need `datetime2-calc.sty`, which is automatically loaded through the `calc` or `showdow` package options. (Make sure you have at least v1.3 of `datetime2` unless you just want to use the `pgfcalendar` commands). **These language-sensitive commands are non-expandable for both packages.**

### Month Name

- `datetime`

  The language-sensitive command `\monthname` takes an optional argument, but it's far more complicated than simply doing `\monthname`*dialect* as it tries to ensure that the relevant regional file `dt-`*dialect*`.def` has been loaded. If the control sequence given by `monthname\languagename` doesn't exist, it falls back on `\monthnameenglish`, which is always defined. This command can't be used in expandable contexts. Example:

  ```
  \monthname[1]
  ```

  Where supported, there are analogous commands for abbreviated and first letter upper case use.
- `datetime2` (`datetime2-calc.sty` required)

  Since `datetime2-calc` automatically loads the `pgfcalendar` package, you can use the commands provided by that package, such as `\pgfcalendarmonthname`. For example:

  ```
  \pgfcalendarmonthname{1}
  ```

  As from v1.3, `datetime2-calc` also provides `\DTMmonthname`. As with `datetime`'s `\monthname`, this is far more complicated than simply doing `\DTM`*language*`monthname`, but in this case you have to ensure that the relevant language module has been loaded as loading modules on-the-fly in the middle of a document can have some unpleasant side-effects. Example:

  ```
  \DTMmonthname{1}
  ```

  This command uses `\pgfcalendarmonthname` as a fallback. Where supported, there are analogous commands for abbreviated and first letter upper case use.

### Day of Week Name

- `datetime`

  The week day name for the current language can be obtained with the command `\dayofweeknameid`. As with `\monthname`, this performs a check to determine if the relevant language file has been loaded. If the control sequence given by `dayofweeknameid\languagename` exists, that's used otherwise `\dayofweeknameidenglish` is used as a fallback. Example:

  ```
  \dayofweeknameid{3}
  ```

  Again, where supported, there are analogous commands for the abbreviated or first letter upper case versions.
- `datetime2`

  The week day name can be obtained through `\pgfcalendarweekdayname` or (`datetime2` v1.3 onwards) `\DTMweekdayname`, which behaves in a similar way to `\DTMmonthname`. The `pgfcalendar` command is used as a fallback if the weekday name isn't supported for the current language. Example:

  ```
  \DTMweekdayname{1}
  ```

  Again, where supported, there are analogous commands for the abbreviated or first letter upper case versions.

### Day of Month

- `datetime`

  The language-sensitive day of month can be displayed using `\ordinaldate`. Again, this performs a check to determine if the appropriate language file has been loaded. If the control sequence given by `ordinaldate\languagename` is defined, then that's used otherwise the argument is simply displayed without any formatting. Example:

  ```
  \ordinaldate{19}
  ```
- `datetime2`

  The `datetime2-calc` package (v1.3 onwards) provides `\DTMordinal`. Example:

  ```
  \DTMordinal{19}
  ```

  This just displays the number as a fallback if support for the current language isn't provided.

Example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[en-GB,showdow]{datetime2}

\DTMlangsetup[en-GB]{ord=raise}

\begin{document}

\DTMcomputedayofweekindex{2016-01-19}{\result}
\DTMweekdayname{\result},
\DTMordinal{19}
\DTMmonthname{1}

\end{document}
```

## Comparisons

The examples below use `hyperref` to illustrate the effect in bookmarks and `\pagestyle{headings}` to illustrated the effect in page headings. Ideally, the date should appear in the bookmark on the left and in upper case in the page heading at the top.

### `datetime` with specific language commands

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{datetime}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\pagestyle{headings}

\computedayofweek{19}{1}{2016}

\section{\dayofweeknameidbritish{\the\dayofweek}, 
\protect\ordinaldatebritish{19}
\monthnamebritish[1] (\languagename)}

\end{document}
```

Produces:

[image: image of page with incorrect bookmark and header]

### `datetime2` with specific language commands

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[en-GB,calc]{datetime2}

\DTMlangsetup[en-GB]{ord=raise}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\pagestyle{headings}

\DTMcomputedayofweekindex{2016-01-19}{\result}

\section{\DTMenglishweekdayname{\result}, \DTMenglishordinal{19} 
\DTMenglishmonthname{1} (\languagename)}

\end{document}
```

Produces (best result):

[image: image of page with correct bookmarks and headings]

### `datetime` with language-sensitive commands

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{datetime}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\pagestyle{headings}

\computedayofweek{19}{1}{2016}

\section{\dayofweeknameid{\the\dayofweek}, \ordinaldate{19}
\monthname[1] (\languagename)}

\end{document}
```

Produces:

[image: image of page with incorrect bookmark and header]

### `datetime2` with language-sensitive commands

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[en-GB,calc]{datetime2}

\DTMlangsetup[en-GB]{ord=raise}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\pagestyle{headings}

\DTMcomputedayofweekindex{2016-01-19}{\result}

\section{\DTMweekdayname{\result}, \DTMordinal{19} \DTMmonthname{1}
(\languagename)}

\end{document}
```

Produces

[image: image of page with incorrect bookmarks and headers]