# date format for specific date

Tags: datetime, date

I am using the package like this:

```
\usepackage[nodayofweek, short]{datetime}
```

So when I am using `\today` it shows exactly what I want like this:

[image]

So I have two questions. One, how to omit the year? Two, how to show a specific date in a format like this, for example, Jun 15th.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: `\formatdate{<day>}{<month>}{<year>}` formats the given date in the current format. You can define a new format with `\newdateformat{mydateformat}{\ordinaldate{} \shortmonthname}` and then say `\mydateformat\formatdate{<day>}{<month>}{<year>}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`datetime` is obsolete, you should be using `datetime2` instead. Which has excellent documentation, by the way (not to mention a lot of threads on this forum.) That said, take a look at this MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[en-GB]{datetime2}
\DTMlangsetup[en-GB]{ord=raise,showyear=true}

\begin{document}

\today

\DTMdate{2023-06-15} 

\DTMlangsetup[en-GB]{showyear=false}
\DTMdate{2023-07-05}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Give me bilingual support for Welsh and English in `datetime2` and I'll 'upgrade' from `datetime`. Until then ... ;). (I know this is not the OP's question, but `datetime` supports functionality I need - not everybody is supported by `datetime2`.)

Comment: See e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/261641/how-do-i-extract-a-month-name-in-datetime2/261646#261646. (I gather from Nicola's updated answer that `datetime2` may now be a bit more flexible, But if you want Welsh dates, you'll still get the wrong output for e.g. ordinals. I have a corrected version for `datetime` (which I'm not allowed to distribute without renaming), but zilch for `datetime2`. The code for the latter is far beyond me, so I can't roll my own the way I did for `datetime`.)

Comment: Obviously this was in reply to OP's question. He seems to be from Hong Kong, and supposedly content using a British standard date format. If an author publicly states that his package is „obsolete” and points to a successor, that's usually good enough for most users – unless they have a specific reason not to upgrade and know what they're doing.

Comment: Yes, because 'obsolete' typically means the functionality is provided in a better way by some alternative. In this case, that's absolutely not the case. I'd have no problem if the package author declared it 'unmaintained' but declaring it obsolete risks getting it removed from distros etc., even though there's no alternative for (some) minority languages. The Welsh version still includes bits I'm told are Breton. (So does `datetime`, but that's easy to correct.) I can't even distribute the corrected file for `datetime` except with an instruction to rename it b/c it would violate the licence.