# Date without year

Tags: datetime2

I would like the dates language within a document controlled by package.  It seems that `datetime2` is the only contemporary package doing this stuff.  However, occasionally I need only to display day and month without year, i.e.

```
21th March
```

Is that possible?  I know that there is undocumented (!) `showdayofmonth` flag ([Month/Year Format in Latex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/212263/month-year-format-in-latex/312603)) that does that for the day, but I couldn't find similar for the year.

Maybe I should try another package?  Maybe `babel`?  What would you suggest?

MWE

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[english,main=british]{babel}
\usepackage[useregional]{datetime2}

\begin{document}

\DTMDisplaydate{0}{2}{10}{-1}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you make a small MWE to make it faster to try answers?

Comment: Defining a new command derived from datetime2.

Comment: @Bernard but this command will not work for different languages?

Comment: I don't know, as I haven't looked into the code of the package, but I think it should be possible to patch one of the commands to obtain what you want.

Comment: Actually when reading the source code of `datetime2` I found that there is an undocumented `showyear` key: `\DTMlangsetup*{showyear=false}`. Related question (but not duplicate): https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/358256/datetime2-warnings-when-using-showyear-setting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Edit: there is an undocumented `showyear` key. You can apply this for a single language using for example `\DTMsetbool{en-GB}{showyear}{false}` or for all languages using `\DTMlangsetup{showyear=false}`. The second version issues a warning because the key is not applicable to some regions in the hierarchy, such as `english-base`. This warning can be suppressed using `\DTMlangsetup*` (see [datetime2 -- Warnings when using showyear setting](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/358256/datetime2-warnings-when-using-showyear-setting)).

This setting changes the behavior of `\DTMDisplaydate` throughout the document, but you can reset it after use.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[english,main=british]{babel}
\usepackage[useregional]{datetime2}

\begin{document}

\DTMlangsetup*{showyear=false}
\DTMDisplaydate{2020}{2}{10}{-1} is the date

\DTMlangsetup*{showyear=true}
\DTMDisplaydate{2020}{2}{10}{-1} is the date

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

---

Original answer:

You can define a new date format without year, as described in the [manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/datetime2/datetime2.pdf) (e.g., page 96 and further).

When you want to use the new format you need to set it using `\DTMsetdatestyle` which will affect `\DTMDisplaydate`. It does not seem possible to set it just for single use, so afterwards you need to reset the style to what it was before, in the MWE this is `en-GB` (because of `main=british`). Note that you need to add the `calc` package option for `datetime2` to use the `\DTMmonthname` macro.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[english,main=british]{babel}
\usepackage[useregional,calc]{datetime2}

\begin{document}

\DTMnewdatestyle{noyear}{%
\renewcommand{\DTMdisplaydate}[4]{%
\DTMenglishordinal{##3} \DTMmonthname{##2}}%
}
\DTMsetdatestyle{noyear}
\DTMDisplaydate{2020}{2}{10}{-1}

\DTMsetdatestyle{en-GB}
\DTMDisplaydate{2020}{2}{10}{-1}

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Note that the redefinition includes `\DTMenglishordinal` in order to keep the ordinal (th) from being printed as superscript. A more international version is `\ordinalnum` from the `fmtcount` package (which supports a number of European languages) but only as superscript as far as I know.

Comment: The problem with this solution is that it is not language independent.  Is it possible to remove year from all language date displays?

Answer (score 2):

I introduce `\stripyear` to help.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[english,main=british]{babel}
\usepackage[useregional]{datetime2}
\newcommand\stripyear[1]{%
  \edef\tmp{#1}\expandafter\stripyearaux\tmp\relax}
\def\stripyearaux#1 #2 #3\relax{#1 #2}
\begin{document}
\stripyear{\DTMDisplaydate{2020}{2}{10}{-1}}.
\end{document}
```

[image]